# Select para mostrar clientes que não estão em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Qual a forma correta para apresentar minha tabela de clientes com as seguintes cláusulas:
Estar a mais de 60 dias sem compra, não estar na tabela de Ligações ou estar ter mais de 20 dias desde a ultima ligação.

Campos tabela Cliente
CNPJ, Cliente, Data Ultima Compra

Campos Ligações
CNPJ, Data Ligação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O recomendável neste site é você sempre mostrar o que tentou fazer e se ocorreu algum erro ou o resultado obtido não foi o esperado.

Este não é um site para apenas pedir que façam alguma coisa para você. Usualmente tal tipo de pergunta é simplesmente rejeitada.

Como você é novato, vou relevar mas faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) sobre como usar este site.

Tente:

```
SELECT Clientes.* FROM Clientes INNER JOIN Ligações ON (Cliente.CNPJ = Ligações.CNPJ)
WHERE (Cliente.Data_ultima_compra < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, 60 DAY))
    OR (Ligações.CNPJ IS NULL)
    OR (Ligações.Data_ligação IS NOT NULL AND Ligações.Data_ligação < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, 20 DAY));
```

Comment: Realizei somente a mudanças de Inner Join para Left Join, pois os valores mostrados serão todos da tabela de clientes. Grato!

Comment: Correto, falha de digitação. Não tem sentido testar (Ligações.CNPJ IS NULL) em uma INNER JOIN.